# How to take cell reference location and obtain value from another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Attempting to create logic in a sheet which looksup from a list of string names and finds the next one on the list. Im using a few functions which provide the absolute reference or something similar, but I cannot seem to figure out how to pass this to another function to get the value from the cell

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(LookupSheet!A1:LookupSheet!A30,MATCH(F2,LookupSheet!A1:Roles!A30,0)+1))
```

This will return something like

```
[MyFileName]LookupSheet!A$12
```

So I am getting the right reference, but unsure how to get the value using what cell function returns.

Comment: Just use the INDEX and MATCH portion and discard the CELL bit.

Comment: Naturally BigBen is right. Still, in case you still want an answer for the problem (return a cell's value knowing its address), the function INDIRECT is probably what you were looking for.

Comment: If you refer to a range from another sheet you only need to enter the name of the sheet once, no need to repeat. `LookupSheet!A1:A30`
But what does this mean `LookupSheet!A1:Roles!A30` ?